# How to specify path from where library loader can look for those libraries?

Tags: eclipse

I am developing a eclipse plugin which uses 3 native libraries, lets call them lib1.so, lib2.so and lib3.so. Dependency among these libraries goes like this lib1.so --> lib2.so --> lib3.so.

I can load **lib1.so** library using **System.loadLibrary()** API, but I am getting unsatisfied linker error for **lib2.so** and **lib3.so**. I resolved this issue by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to path where I kept all these 3 libraries.

I am not happy with this fix as I have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH every time when I am importing these plugin projects in other machines :(

Is there any other way such that lib1.so can load lib2.so and lib2.so can lib3.so automatically. And these libraries always be kept together in single folder.

Comment: You ought to be able to write code in your plugin startup logic in the Activator to set that variable, usually based on the install location of your plugin.

Comment: Use [Bundle-NativeCode](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/07/27/osgi/)

Comment: yes it tells about only single library. I am not facing any problem with single library. I can not load libraries without specifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH when I have more than one native libs. This issue is blocking me to make my plugins installable from zip folder or from web link.